# Using VS11 with VS2010 projects

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

If I am reading [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh266747%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) correctly, I should be able to use VS2010 solutions/projects in VS11 without any ill affects on my co-workers who are still using VS2010.

My projects are mostly c# Winforms and ASP.NET web services apps.
Has anyone tried this setup?  Has it really worked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it works fine, I use VS11 Beta every day, where as the rest of the company uses VS2010.

Note, you need to make sure that the VS2010 users have applied Visual Studio 2010 **Service Pack 1**. If not, then they cannot open a solution file saved by VS11.

Here's the [Official MS Answer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh266747%28VS.110%29.aspx).

Few caveats I have found:

- Using **just** VS11 without 2010 installed required me to update a number of project files, and some references to the VS2010 tools (i.e. sgen). If you are planning on using VS11, just install it along side VS2010.
- We have custom FXCop rule in an assembly. We needed to re-compile this using VS11 to get it to work with VS11. But we cannot check it in, because it breaks 2010. I asked a question on [MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vseditor/thread/f5d9dcbf-cb42-4ff0-9d06-5bfaec1d3594/#f5d9dcbf-cb42-4ff0-9d06-5bfaec1d3594) a few months ago for a workaround, but got no reply.